# scheduling with cronjob to run the php file for only one time

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

how to run the php file only for once using the cron jobs.
i.e., to schedule task to work on 20/06/2015 10:30:00

I tried something like this :

`30 10 20 6 ? 2015 /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/file/application.php`

but it is not working.

I just want to schedule it for future but do not want to repeat it. How to do it ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: I've had this issue, to help address it, I developed a service scheduledwebhook.com. It allows you to specify when an event should be triggered and the destination for the data. If this sounds like it might meet your needs, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *     *     *   *    *        Your application file or command 
 -     -     -   -    -
 |     |     |   |    |
 |     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
 |     |     |   +------- month in numbers (1 - 12)
 |     |     +--------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
 +------------- min (0 - 59)
```

> 21 12 13 6 0 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/run.php

this works for me every time

Comment: if I use '?' it gives an error  "/tmp/crontab.6WdWbT":1: bad day-of-week
errors in crontab file, can't install

Comment: see what week day is on that day, and can give its numeric value, cannot be wrong if you want to execute it on a particular day. like for many applications cron runs on saturday or sunday in that case.. the week becomes 0 or 6

Comment: the example which you gave will execute when the month is '6' right ? that means every year. But I want it to be executed 'only once in lifetime'

Comment: Cron job is a time based job scheduler, meant and created to be executed on particular time, so it is its basic working. if you want to run your cron once in life time dont create a cron instead create the file keep all your code in it and hit the url manually on that particular date.

Comment: just like in Facebook, you can schedule your status, I am trying to do it for only one time or is there any other way ?

Comment: You can use database, and maintain a table as todo list, which will hold your task, now set your cron to be executed once daily, and with that cron check the table for any task, of that day. if found then execute the task. For example, there is a db where you have status, run cron check if a status needs to be set on that day. if found run the script for user and set the status.